# How can you render a visually meaningful 2D FFT in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, fft

I have created a filter which is meant to render a 2D FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of an image. In the actual application the images are coming from a live data feed. The problem is only the extremely low frequencies are registering so all I see is a flat gray image with a dot in the top left (lowest frequency).  Can anyone suggest a way of repairing this code so it displays more than  a flat image with a few dots in the top left corner?

I believe this is the problem area in the code. This squares the 2D FFT Result to eliminate the imaginary part and then scales it.

```
            ctmp.setTo(result_r[x][y]); // Copy Result to ctmp
            ctmp.mult(result_r[x][y]); // Square the result to eliminate imaginary part

            cval = 127 + (127 * ctmp.real/ max);
            tmpc = (int) Math.floor(cval);
            //System.out.println(String.format("tmpc=%d %f",tmpc,ctmp.real));
            if (tmpc > 255d) {
                rgb |=  255 << 16;    
            } else if (tmpc >= 0d){
                rgb |= ((tmpc << 16) & (255 << 16));
            }
```

Full source

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package physics.filters;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

import physics.Filter;

// http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wm2a/applets/Transformation/Complex.java
import physics.helpers.Complex;

// http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wm2a/applets/Transformation/Fourier2D.java
import physics.helpers.Fourier2D;

/**
 *
 * @author rritoch
 */
public class FFTFilter 
    implements Filter {

    BufferedImage last = null;
    boolean is_init = false;

    int imageW;
    int imageH;
    int fftW;
    int fftH;
    BufferedImage fftImage;
    Fourier2D fourier2d;

    Complex[][] complex2d_r; // red buffer
    Complex[][] complex2d_g; // green buffer
    Complex[][] complex2d_b; // blue buffer

    public static BufferedImage cloneImage(BufferedImage bi) {
        ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
        return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    }   

    /**
     * Init/Re-init Cache
     *
     */

    void computeParams(BufferedImage in) {
        imageW = in.getWidth();
        imageH = in.getHeight();
        fftW = 1;
        fftH = 1;

        while(fftW < imageW) {
            fftW = fftW << 1;
        }

        while(fftH < imageH) {
            fftH = fftH << 1;
        }

        fftImage = new BufferedImage(fftW, fftH, in.getType());

        fourier2d = new Fourier2D(fftW,fftH);
        complex2d_r = new Complex[fftW][];
        complex2d_g = new Complex[fftW][];
        complex2d_b = new Complex[fftW][];

        for(int idx=0;idx<fftW;idx++) {
            complex2d_r[idx] = new Complex[fftH];
            complex2d_g[idx] = new Complex[fftH];
            complex2d_b[idx] = new Complex[fftH];
            for(int idy=0;idy<fftH;idy++) {
                complex2d_r[idx][idy] = new Complex();
                complex2d_g[idx][idy] = new Complex();
                complex2d_b[idx][idy] = new Complex();
            }
        }


        System.out.println(String.format("Init FFTFilter (%d,%d)!",fftW,fftH));
    }

    void fft(BufferedImage img) 
    {
        Graphics2D gr;
        Complex[][] result_r;
        Complex[][] result_g;
        Complex[][] result_b;
        int x,y;
        Complex ctmp = new Complex();
        double cval;
        int rgb,tmpc;


        gr = fftImage.createGraphics();
        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, fftW, fftH, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
        gr.dispose();

        // Copy values from img to complex2d
        for(y=0;y<fftH;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<fftW;x++) {

                rgb = fftImage.getRGB(x,y);
                double r = new Double(rgb & 255);
                double g = new Double((rgb >> 8) & 255);
                double b = new Double((rgb >> 16) & 255);
                complex2d_r[x][y].imag = 0;
                complex2d_r[x][y].real = r - 127d;
                complex2d_g[x][y].imag = 0;
                complex2d_g[x][y].real = g - 127d;
                complex2d_b[x][y].imag = 0;
                complex2d_b[x][y].real = b - 127d;
            }
        }


        // Calculate FFT
        result_r = fourier2d.fft(complex2d_r);
        result_g = fourier2d.fft(complex2d_g);
        result_b = fourier2d.fft(complex2d_b);

        // Scan result for Min & Max

        double max = 0;
        double min = 0;

        for(y=0;y<fftH;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<fftW;x++) {
                ctmp.setTo(result_r[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_r[x][y]);
                if (ctmp.real > max) {
                    max = ctmp.real;
                } else if (ctmp.real < min) {
                    min = ctmp.real;
                }

                ctmp.setTo(result_g[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_g[x][y]);

                if (ctmp.real > max) {
                    max = ctmp.real;
                } else if (ctmp.real < min) {
                    min = ctmp.real;
                }

                ctmp.setTo(result_b[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_b[x][y]);

                if (ctmp.real > max) {
                    max = ctmp.real;
                } else if (ctmp.real < min) {
                    min = ctmp.real;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Size: %f,%f",min,max));

        // compute absolute max
        max = Math.abs(min) > max ? Math.abs(min) : max;

        // Map result onto fftImage

        for(y=0;y<fftH;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<fftW;x++) {

                rgb = 0;

                ctmp.setTo(result_r[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_r[x][y]);

                cval = 127 + (127 * ctmp.real/ max);
                tmpc = (int) Math.floor(cval);
                //System.out.println(String.format("tmpc=%d %f",tmpc,ctmp.real));
                if (tmpc > 255d) {
                    rgb |=  255 << 16;    
                } else if (tmpc >= 0d){
                    rgb |= ((tmpc << 16) & (255 << 16));
                }

                ctmp.setTo(result_g[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_g[x][y]);

                cval = 127 + (127 * ctmp.real/ max);
                tmpc = (int) Math.floor(cval);
                if (tmpc > 255d) {
                    rgb |=  255 << 8;    
                } else if (tmpc >= 0d){
                    rgb |= ((tmpc << 8) & (255 << 8));
                }

                ctmp.setTo(result_b[x][y]);
                ctmp.mult(result_b[x][y]);
                cval = 127 + (127 * ctmp.real/ max);
                tmpc = (int) Math.floor(cval);
                if (tmpc > 255d) {
                    rgb |=  255;    
                } else if (tmpc >= 0d){
                    rgb |= (tmpc & 255);
                }
                fftImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
        // Copy fft Image to image
        gr = img.createGraphics();
        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        gr.drawImage(fftImage, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0, 0, fftImage.getWidth(), fftImage.getHeight(), null);
        gr.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedImage filter(BufferedImage in) {

        if (last == null || last.getWidth() != in.getWidth() || last.getHeight() != in.getHeight()) {
            computeParams(in);
        }

        BufferedImage ret = cloneImage(in);
        fft(ret);

        last = in;
        return ret;
    }


}
```

Note: This is my first time using this particular FFT and I haven't verified if the FFT algorithm is correct so I am going off of the assumption that the FFT algorithm is correct.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but most people won't read through all that code it is just too long. Can you pinpoint the exact location of the problem?

Comment: How a bout writing a test first to check if your FFT algorithm is correct before looking for other possible problems?

Comment: @Adam Arnold, good point. I isolated the code that I believe is the problem

Comment: @MrSmith42, isn't that a chicken and egg problem? I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: @Ralph Ritoch: I do not think so I can generate an image, of which I already know the included frquencies. That can be used to test the FFT implementation.

Comment: My name **is not *Arnold***.

Comment: @Adom Arold, Sorry it was an honest mistake.

Comment: As a wild guess, could it be there some kind of numerical overflow during calculations?

Comment: @Victor Sorokin, I believe I've  already corrected that problem. Originally the code was using complex2d_r[x][y].real = r/255d; which I changed to complex2d_r[x][y].real = r - 127d; to avoid the "underflow" where FFT results were so small floating point errors were pushing the results to zero. I'll re-test again though to see if I'm still having underflow problems.

Comment: While it didn't help much I tried scaling with Math.log, it made my dot in the top left a little larger, but still not significant enough to say the 2D FFT rendering contains a significant amount of information.

Comment: I finally was able to see something by not only scaling by ln but also by multiplying the result by 2 million using cval = 127 + (s * 127 * ((ctmp.real / Math.abs(ctmp.real)) * Math.log(1 + Math.abs(ctmp.real)))/ max); where s = 2 million in the final calculation and ctmp.real = ((ctmp.real / Math.abs(ctmp.real)) * Math.log(1 + Math.abs(ctmp.real))); for the max calculation. This solution is horrible though because there is a HUGE amount of information loss as many values are getting clipped because they're above or below the 0-255 RGB range.

Comment: My name **is not *Adom***.

Comment: You should try plotting the Absolute value of it on logarithmic scales not a linear one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that these lines don't eliminate imaginary part

```
ctmp.setTo(result_r[x][y]); // Copy Result to ctmp
ctmp.mult(result_r[x][y]); // Square the result to eliminate imaginary part
```

(a + i*b)(a+ i*b)= a^2 - b^2 + **i*(a+b)**

I'd suggest that you need an amplitude (modulus) of complex number

```
Amp = Sqrt(ctmp.real^2 + ctmp.imaginary^2)
```

(probably you have special function in complex class)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I tried this and it was very helpful. I still needed to scale it using Math.log() and x 1000 to get decent resolution, but using the mod function did make the output better. Is it possible to get an inverse of this function for an iFFT back to the original?

Comment: No, you need to make inverse FFT with complex data (real and imaginary parts)

Comment: MBo by "meaningful" I actually mean I want to have enough information in the result to decompose it back to the original. No image has visual imaginary parts so if what your saying is true, than the FFT process itself doubles the amount of information which seems to be a violation of the conservation of information principal.

Comment: Pure real source data give complex FFT result with central symmetry (left part is mirror of the right one), so there is no doubling of information amount